# Does tenure generally account for extended research in a different field?

Tags: tenure-track, india, academic-freedom, non-tenure

I am a working professional in India looking towards a career in research and thus interested in academia. However, apart from having a definite field of interest that motivates my direction in academia, I intend to spend time pursuing major research (that requires minimal to no funding, as it is mostly theoretical) in another field in the future which might not particularly ally with the primary field of interest.

If I do finally graduate to a tenured position in the future, does the promised "freedom" of tenured positions account for freedom to pursue extended research in a divergent field ? Alternatively, for those willing to answer, a more general question might be: what are the terms and conditions or obligatory research output specifications of tenured roles generally ? (Specifically India, but I'm also interested in how it is abroad)

Comment: @Buffy Yes, I'll edit the question to add that. Thanks.

Comment: US based answer: if you are, say, a math professor, then your research output *in math* (or a very closely related area) is what is going to count when your research productivity is being evaluated. If you spent your time composing a symphony, or publishing essays about medieval Japanese weapon-making techniques, that’s not going to count, even if those things are valid scholarship from the point of view of other disciplines. I hope these examples make the general principle clear…

Comment: @DanRomik Thanks for the reply ! Are there any specific benchmarks for this productivity or is it evaluated by committee ?

Comment: This is not a question that can be answered in a short comment. In any case I have no knowledge of how these processes work in India.

Comment: @DanRomik Understandable, thanks nonetheless !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an India specific answer, but more based on general principles. First, [tenure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_tenure) is understood differently in different places and is related to, but not the same as [academic freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_freedom). Tenure is a surprisingly recent practice, actually.

Generally speaking, if you hold tenure, then you can be fired only for cause, such as misconduct or institutional financial reasons. It is intended to protect the work of academics from governmental interference and censure. Basically, it says you can explore unpopular ideas.

But tenure doesn't mean that you need to be rewarded in any way for what you study or what you write. If you are tenured in a mathematics department, then rewards will come from your contributions to that field and to that department, and not much else, though external service is often rewarded somewhat.

So, if you want to be successful in a math department, you have to "do" math and teach it effectively. Other things may not be rewarded at all. And, if they reduce your effectiveness in the math department, nothing about tenure says that the head can't give you some unpleasant duties that you have to carry out to avoid a charge of misconduct; a heavy teaching load, perhaps.

Some people, however, are able to hold dual appointments. A mathematician might also work in the philosophy department, for example and hold dual appointments. At tenure, the person would probably be given some special assurance that this will work for them. It might even be possible, though I can't name a case, in which you hold tenure in more than one department.

So, tenure is about what you can and can't be fired for and having outside interests or unpopular ideas isn't one of the bad things. But your employment contract also specifies expectations that you must meet. Life might be unpleasant if you don't meet them because of other interests.

I've known people (tenured, actually) who couldn't advance beyond associate professor because they had those outside interests that got in the way of their main tasks. Over time they got larger teaching loads of lower level courses.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question !